# Get matching value of a regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm kinda lost with regex ATM.

I've the following link:

```
 http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT?list=UUDvJQzC6YfBdOMkbQGUekOg
```

And I need to retrieve the value after "/embed/" and before "?list".

So I did the following:

```
String re1="(embed)";   // Word 1
String re2="(\\/)"; // Any Single Character 1
String re3="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 2
String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re5="(\\?)"; // Any Single Character 2
```

However, when I split the link with:

```
String[] split = youtubeLink.split( regex );
```

Doesn't seem to be working.

Any tips?

Comment: What is your output? And what is `regex`?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
    String str="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT?list=UUDvJQzC6YfBdOMkbQGUekOg";

    String re1="(embed)";   // Word 1
    String re2="(\\/)"; // Any Single Character 1
    String re3="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 2
    String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re5="(\\?)"; // Any Single Character 2

    String []st1=str.split("embed\\/");
    String []st2=st1[1].split("\\?list");

    System.out.println(st2[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

simply you can use this code to get the tail part

```
String s="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT?list=UUDvJQzC6YfBdOMkbQGUekOg";
s=s.split("/embed/")[1].split("\\?list")[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the group from this one:

```
^.*/([^/\?]*)\?[^/\?]*$
```

- `^`: start of line
- `.*`: anything
- `/`: literal `/`
- `([^/\?]*)`: a group not containing `/` and `?`
- `\?`: literal `?`
- `[^/\?]*`: anything but `/` and `?`
- `$`: end of the line

I didn't test it, but something like this should work.
As we are using a Java string, each `\` from the expression above must be written as `\\`.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
// ...
Pattern.compile("^.*/([^/\\?]*)\\?[^/\\?]*$")
       .matcher(input)
       .group(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you want to get name of resource.
In that case you shouldn't be using regex but `URL` and `File` classes.

```
String s = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT?list=UUDvJQzC6YfBdOMkbQGUekOg";
URL url = new URL(s);
File f = new File(url.getPath());//url.getPath() returns "/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT"
String resourceName = f.getName();
System.out.println(resourceName);
```

Output: `SomER1aNdomTexT`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
(?<=\/embed\/).*(?=\?list)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do something like this :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern
    .compile("^(?:.(?!embed))+/embed/((?:.(?!list))+)\\?list.*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern
    .matcher("http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomER1aNdomTexT?list=UUDvJQzC6YfBdOMkbQGUekOg");
if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```